# Sending CTRL with a Symbol DS6878 barcode scanner

Tags: keyboard, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to program the scanner to send the CTRL key?.  The CTRL key is used like a reset button on our systems, and we are constantly having to track down the keyboard to hit the CTRL key.

Comment: If you can't program the scanner that way, you may want to use a programmable foot swith or keyboard that allows sending the CTRL key.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be no, but it depends entirely on your computer, scanner, and application.

The reason is that most scanners can [only decode ASCII data](http://www.makebarcode.com/info/appnote/app_016.html), which precludes you from using keyboard control codes like ctrl or F1.

Ctrl is a bit of a special case since in ASCII, it only [*modifies* other characters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html) (note: there is no ASCII code for the key), rather than sending a character itself.

That said, per that first link, some scanners have special logic in them that can scan one character and replace it with another in the output, and Code 128, which your scanner supports, supports these enhancements. Try scanning a code that has a "Ctrl-something" key combo.. this may work.